# How can I extract the numbers from a string and store them into variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string containing numbers, I need to extract the numbers from the string and store them into variables. For example, if my user input is:

- "make a C++ program that adds 2 numbers together"

Then I need to extract the `2` and store it in a variable.

I tried this:

```
function hasNumbers(t)
{
    var regex = /\d/g;
    return regex.test(t);
}
```

Something like this would be good but I'd prefer it not to be a function.

Either something like `var amountOfVariables =` or `if(userInput.includes,isinteger,typeof,` etc.

There has to be a combination of methods that allows you to find a integer in a string & then store it in a variable, right?

I was trying to use `document.write(amountOfVariables);` 
to test if it was being stored but no luck. I know I need to convert the String part into an int.

I want a method or a way to store integers in a users input in variables for later use in functions. But at the moment I can't get this to work.

Comment: Question is too wide. Focus on what you expect from the function, not your whole problem. Maybe you must play with split function and parse.  Example '10,3,4'.split(",") and parse each element of array result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If I'm not mistaken, the question requires "contains number", not "is number". So:**

```
function hasNumber(myString) {
  return /\d/.test(myString);
}
```

Comment: but how do i store that in a variable? that just tests if it contains a number

Comment: what do you want to store in variable? in this function if you pass the string it will return true if it has number otherwise false

Comment: " make a C++ program that adds 2 numbers together"  im making a program that reads what the user inputs then makes it happen.  so the 2 should go into amountOfVariables or whatever i choose to name the variable then i can use that 2 to make 2 int variables that start at default. then add those 2 default values. then the user can copy and paste this information and edit the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. not sure if i can use this to find more then 1 number in a string though

```
    const [amountOfVariables] = userInput.match(/\d+/g) || [NaN];

        parseInt(amountOfVariables)




    document.write(amountOfVariables);
```

This searches the string for a number then stores it in a variable